# Get unique array of month and years between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two `Date` objects, for example:

```
first = Fri, 02 Dec 2016 
last = Wed, 01 Mar 2017
```

What is the most efficient way to get a unique array of months and years between them?  In this case I'm after:

```
Dec 2016
Jan 2017
Feb 2017
Mar 2017
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
require 'date'
```

```
def doit(first, last)
  first = first << 1
  (12*last.year + last.month - 12*first.year - first.month + 1).
    times.map { |i| (first = first >> 1).strftime("%b %Y") }
end
```

```
first = Date.parse('Fri, 02 Dec 2016')
last  = Date.parse('Wed, 01 Mar 2017')
```

```
doit(first, last)
  #=> ["Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017"]
```

Note that

```
(12*last.year + last.month - 12*first.year - first.month + 1)
```

equals the number of months covered by the range.

Comment: Wow, this is by far the fastest solution. Nice!

Comment: I made a few changes to my answer. Initially I used `"%s %s" % [Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[f.month], f.year]`, but after seeing that everyone else used `strftime("%b %Y")` I recognized the folly of my ways.

Answer (score 4):

You could create an array of dates, then use `strftime` to set the correct format, and `uniq` to avoid repeated values, like this:

```
(first..last).map{ |date| date.strftime("%b %Y") }.uniq
#=> ["Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017"]
```

Comment: This calls `strftime` for every day in the date range, which could be slow if the range is large.

Comment: @MátéSolymosi Yes, you are correct, although the difference will be almost negligible (unless, of course, it is used to query hundreds of years).

Comment: True, that's not a realistic scenario.

Comment: @MátéSolymosi But still takes twice the time, so its good to note it.

Answer (score 3):

Since user asks for ***most efficient way*** (and just for fun) here's a simple benchmark of the proposed solutions:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bmbm(10) do |bm|
  bm.report('Cary') do
    first = Date.new(1000, 1, 1)
    last  = Date.new(2100, 1, 1)

    def doit(first, last)
      (12*last.year + last.month - 12*first.year - first.month).times.map do
        first.strftime("%b %Y")
        first = first >> 1
      end
    end

    doit(first, last)
  end

  bm.report('Simple Lime') do
    first = Date.new(1000, 1, 1)
    last  = Date.new(2100, 1, 1)

    dates = []

    while first.beginning_of_month < last.end_of_month
      dates << first.strftime("%b %Y")

      first = first.next_month
    end
  end

  bm.report('Máté') do
    first = Date.new(1000, 1, 1)
    last  = Date.new(2100, 1, 1)

    (first.beginning_of_month..last).map { |d| d.strftime("%b %Y") if d.day == 1 }.compact
  end

  bm.report('Gerry/Dan') do
    first = Date.new(1000, 1, 1)
    last  = Date.new(2100, 1, 1)

    (first..last).map{ |date| date.strftime("%b %Y") }.uniq
  end
end
```

Results:

```
Rehearsal -----------------------------------------------
Cary          0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.025968)
Simple Lime   0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.192860)
Máté          0.460000   0.020000   0.480000 (  0.481839)
Gerry/Dan     0.810000   0.020000   0.830000 (  0.835931)
-------------------------------------- total: 1.520000sec

                  user     system      total        real
Cary          0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.024871)
Simple Lime   0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.150696)
Máté          0.390000   0.010000   0.400000 (  0.398637)
Gerry/Dan     0.710000   0.010000   0.720000 (  0.711155)
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for going to the extra effort to prove which is the most efficient!

Answer (score 2):

Not a pretty one-liner, but also doesn't walk through each day individually so should be a fair bit faster for large ranges.

```
first = Date.new(2016, 12, 2)
last = Date.new(2017, 3, 1)

dates = []
while first.beginning_of_month < last.end_of_month
  dates << first.strftime("%b %Y")

  first = first.next_month
end

puts dates.inspect
# => ["Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these variables:

```
first = Date.new(2016, 12, 2)
last = Date.new(2017, 3, 1)
```

A one-liner solution:

```
(first.beginning_of_month..last).map { |d| d.strftime("%b %Y") if d.day == 1 }.compact
#=> ["Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017"]
```

Comment: not quite what I'm after, this solution includes the day which I don't need, just the month and the year i.e Dec 2016

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
start_date=Date.new(2016,12,2)
end_date=Date.new(2017,3,1)

(start_date..end_date).map{ |d| d.strftime("%b %Y") }.uniq
 => ["Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017"]
```