# Get empty months in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash of Month->Value

```
{"Apr 2016"=>6, "Aug 2016"=>9, "Jan 2017"=>11, "Apr 2017"=>6, "May 2017"=>9, "Jun 2017"=>1, "Jul 2017"=>9}
```

I would know what is the best way to get all empty months between the first and the last value

I would like something like

```
{"Apr 2016"=>6, May 2016=>0, Jun 2016=>0 .... "Aug 2016"=>9, "Sep 2016" => 0 "Jan 2017"=>11, "Apr 2017"=>6, "May 2017"=>9, "Jun 2017"=>1, "Jul 2017"=>9}
```

Comment: Have you seen "[Get unique array of month and years between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064402/get-unique-array-of-month-and-years-between-two-dates/45064684)"? That question gets all the months between a first and a last as an array...and those answers could be modified pretty easily to fill in a hash's missing months if you can get the first and last month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way, using `each_with_object`:

```
def add_months(dates)
  min, max = dates.keys.map { |date| Date.parse(date) }.minmax
  range    = (min..max).map { |date| date.strftime("%b %Y") }.uniq

  range.each_with_object({}) { |date, result| result[date] = dates[date] || 0 }
end
```

Output:

```
dates = {"Apr 2016"=>6, "Aug 2016"=>9, "Jan 2017"=>11, "Apr 2017"=>6, "May 2017"=>9, "Jun 2017"=>1, "Jul 2017"=>9}

add_months(dates)
#=> {
#     "Apr 2016"=>6,
#     "May 2016"=>0,
#     "Jun 2016"=>0,
#     "Jul 2016"=>0,
#     "Aug 2016"=>9,
#     "Sep 2016"=>0,
#     "Oct 2016"=>0,
#     "Nov 2016"=>0,
#     "Dec 2016"=>0,
#     "Jan 2017"=>11,
#     "Feb 2017"=>0,
#     "Mar 2017"=>0,
#     "Apr 2017"=>6,
#     "May 2017"=>9,
#     "Jun 2017"=>1,
#     "Jul 2017"=>9
#   }
```

Comment: That `.uniq` is not nice, but it's the only way to do it with a simple expression, +1

Comment: @tokland, don't forget we have [Date#>>](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E), which avoids the need to generate a `Date` object for all days between the beginning and end of the range.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, indeed, but try to use it in an idiomatic expression to get the range (no whiles, etc), I found no simple and idiomatic way.

Comment: @tokland, I used `>>` in what I think is an idiomatic expression in my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland. The last expression is too imperative for my taste :) It would be easier to build functional expressions with Rails, which provides some handy helper methods.

Comment: Ok, this is actually tagged rails, so with a month count (like you did in your answer) + a map + date + n.months iteration should be easy.

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
require 'date'

def fill_in_missing_months(dates)
  date_fmt = '%b %Y'
  fm, lm = dates.keys.
                 minmax_by { |date| Date.strptime(date, date_fmt) }.
                 map       { |date| Date.strptime(date, date_fmt) }
  (0..12*(lm.year-fm.year) + lm.month-fm.month).each_with_object({}) do |_,h|
    str = fm.strftime(date_fmt)
    h[str] = dates.fetch(str, 0)
    fm >>= 1
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
dates = {"Apr 2016"=>6, "Aug 2016"=>9, "Jan 2017"=>11, "Apr 2017"=>6,
         "May 2017"=>9, "Jun 2017"=>1, "Jul 2017"=>9}

fill_in_missing_months(dates)
  #=> {"Apr 2016"=>6, "May 2016"=>0, "Jun 2016"=>0, "Jul 2016"=>0, "Aug 2016"=>9,
  #    "Sep 2016"=>0, "Oct 2016"=>0, "Nov 2016"=>0, "Dec 2016"=>0, "Jan 2017"=>11,
  #    "Feb 2017"=>0, "Mar 2017"=>0, "Apr 2017"=>6, "May 2017"=>9, "Jun 2017"=>1,
  # "Jul 2017"=>9}
```

**Explanation**

Experienced Rubiests: A *gory-detail-follows* advisory has been issued, so you may wish to skip the rest of my answer.

Ruby expands `fm >>= 1` to `fm = fm >> 1` when parsing the code. [Date#>>](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E)  advances the date by the number of months given by its argument, which here is `1`.

In addition to `:>>`, see the docs for the methods [Integer#times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-times), [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch), [Date::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime), [Date#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime), [Date#year](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-year), [Date#month](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-month), [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) and [Enumerable#minimax_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by) (not including the more common methods such as `Enumerable#map`). Recall `#` in `Date#year` denotes an instance method whereas `::` in `[Date::strptime]` indicates a class method.

For `dates` given in the example, the steps are as follows.

```
  date_fmt = '%b %Y'
  b = dates.keys
    #=> ["Apr 2016", "Aug 2016", "Jan 2017", "Apr 2017", "May 2017",
    #    "Jun 2017", "Jul 2017"]
  c = b.minmax_by { |date| Date.strptime(date, date_fmt) }
    #=> ["Apr 2016", "Jul 2017"]
  fm, lm = c.map  { |date|  Date.strptime(date, date_fmt) }
    #=> [#<Date: 2016-04-01 ((2457480j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
    #    #<Date: 2017-07-01 ((2457936j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
  fm #=> #<Date: 2016-04-01 ((2457480j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
  lm #=> #<Date: 2017-07-01 ((2457936j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
  d = 0..12*(lm.year-fm.year) + lm.month-fm.month
    #=> 0..15
  e = d.each_with_object({})
    #=> #<Enumerator: 0..15:each_with_object({})>
```

We can see the values that will be generated by `e` and passed to the block by converting it to an array, using [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries) (or [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a)).

```
  e.entries
    #=> [[0, {}], [1, {}],..., [15, {}]]
```

The hashes in these tuples is initially empty, but will be filled in as block calculations are performed.

The first element is generated by `e`, which is passed to the block and the block variables are set equal to its value, using a process called *disambiguation* or *decomposition* to stab out the part associated with each block variable.

```
_,h = e.next
   #=> [0, {}]
h  #=> {}
```

I've used `_` as the first block variable to signify that it (the index) is not used in the block calculation. Continuing,

```
str = fm.strftime(date_fmt)
   #=> "Apr 2016"
h[str] = dates.fetch(str, 0)
   #=> 6
h  #=> {"Apr 2016"=>6}
```

In this case `dates` has a key `"Apr 2016"`, so `h["Apr 2016"]` is set equal to `dates["Apr 2016"]`. In other cases `dates` will not have key equal to `str` (`"May 2016"`, for example), so the value will be set equal to `fetch`'s default value of `0`.

```
fm >>= 1
  #=> #<Date: 2016-05-01 ((2457510j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

`fm` is now May, 2016. The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: Excellent answer, as usual.

Comment: Thanks, @Simple. Fixed it (while wearing a sheepish expression).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to do the above :

```
def normalize_months(month_values)
   ordered_months = month_values.keys.map do |m| Date.parse(m) end.sort.map do |s| s.strftime('%b %Y') end
   normalized = []
   current = ordered_months.first
   while current != ordered_months.last do
     normalized << current
     current = Date.parse(current).next_month.strftime('%b %Y')
   end
   result = {}
   normalized.each do |g| result[g] = month_values[g].nil? ? 0 : month_values[g] end
   result
end
```

Do a `require 'date'` above this if you are doing this using pure ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a method like the following:

```
require 'date'

def add_missing_months(dates)
    # get all months
    months = dates.keys.map{|m| Date.parse(m)}

    # get min and max
    min = months.min
    max = months.max

    # collect all missing months
    missing_months = {}
    while min < max
        min = min.next_month

        missing_months[min.strftime('%b %Y')] = 0 unless months.include?(min) 
    end

    # merge hashes
    dates.merge(missing_months)
end
```